# My Web Host Upgraded from PHP 5.2 to 5.3 and now I'm getting a fatal error in my MediaWiki installation

Tags: php, mediawiki

I have MediaWiki 1.13.3 installed and it has been working fine for a couple years. My web host just upgraded PHP versions on the server from 5.2.17 to 5.3.5, and now all of a sudden I'm getting this error:

```
Warning: Parameter 2 to Parser::parse() expected to be a reference, value given in /usr/www/users/.../includes/StubObject.php on line 58

Fatal error: Call to a member function getCacheTime() on a non-object in /usr/www/users/.../includes/Article.php on line 3387
```

What changed in the new version of PHP that may be causing these errors?

Comment: Please show some code - the lines in question, and possibly their surroundings

Comment: Also if you web hoster change your version of PHP without noticing you, and without a way to keep your old PHP version, that's a good sign that you should choose another web hoster.

Comment: You should upgrade your copy of MediaWiki, and these problems will likely go away.  PHP 5.3 has some object-oriented changes.

Comment: Maybe there is a function call such as `foo($bar = $baz);` at the line indicated in the first error? IIRC such constructs where acceptable prior to 5.3 even when the function expected a reference, but they had to be rewritten as `$bar = $baz; foo($bar);` in 5.3.

Comment: Thanks. I'm attempting to upgrade to 1.16 but I'm having a bit of trouble. I'll try out these suggestions as soon as I can.

Comment: If you have trouble because of the `This script must be run from the command line`: You can use the web updater - http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Upgrading#Web_updater

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Needed to upgrade from mediawiki version 1.13 to 1.16